# Datagridview Sort Icon does not show after disabling Headers VisualStyles

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to add a custom formatting to my row headers.

I wanted to highlight the selected row headers. For this I had to disable Headers VisualStyles.

```
datagridview.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

and apply manual styling for row headers.

but by setting

```
datagridview.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

it affects the **column headers** as well.

Because of that it doesn't show the sorting icon in the column headers anymore. It shows only a line.

How can I set the sorting icon back to normal?